# Multiple Attributes in one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, attributes

I have these properties (A,B) :

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A is required"), DisplayName("A")]
[StringLength(Constants.MaximunStringSize)]
public string A { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "B is required"), DisplayName("B")]
[StringLength(Constants.MaximunStringSize)]
public string B { get; set; }
```

I can create a class that "inherits" all the attributes (DataType, Required, StringLength, DisplayName) and the set through its constructor?. By example:

```
[MyAttribute("A","A is required")]
public string A { get; set; }

[MyAttribute("B","B is required")]
public string B { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can only inherit from _one_ parent. C# does not support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks Oded, so I put quotes around the word heritage. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.

However, for validation attributes, you could create your own validation attribute that contains all of the logic in the existing attributes.

To emulate `[DataType]`, you'll need to implement `IMetadataAware`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no multiple inheritance in C#, so no, you can't do this.

You can, however write your own Attribute that incorporates all the functionality of those attributes.