# RetrieveAttribute-Request for multiple Attributes in one go (Dynamics CRM SOAP)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an interface comminicating with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 (XrmSvcToolkit).
Now, I want to replace this library with Microsoft's SDK SOAP.js. I don't want to change my function calls, but all calls are weakly typed in code, since some are using CRM's REST API.

So now, I want to get information about all attributes of the entity I am adding records to, so I can create valid Sdk.Entity-class objects and send my SOAP-request.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693681/multiple-attributes-in-one) for a request to get a single attribut, but as [this blog entry](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/crm-2015-understanding-crm-metadata/) points out, at least in C# on server-side, it is possible to query more than one attribute.

But what is the JavaScript SOAP-query-way? I need the XML-syntax/scheme of such a request.

Comment: Are you just asking how to retrieve all attributes fro an entity via SOAP using javascript?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://sharpxrmpage.codeplex.com/ otherwise you'll need to write do some code generation or write it by hand.

Comment: Yes, by now, I am retrieving all attributes from an entity via the RetrieveEntityRequest (with <EntityFilter>Attributes</EntityFilter>, found that working) and then filtering through the result. But this is a very tedious, time-taking task.... would be nice to pass some attribute names and retrieve their metadata, so that I save the time spent on filtering. @TravisSharp: I don't want a new library because of the support in CRM 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The RetrieveEntityRequest with EntityFilter.Attributes can provide the attribute metadata and the SOAP Logger can give you the SOAP request.

The SOAP Logger is in the SDK here: SDK\SampleCode\CS\Client\SOAPLogger.

Modified Run method for the SOAP Logger:

```c#
public void Run(ServerConnection.Configuration serverConfig)
{
    try
    {

        // Connect to the Organization service. 
        // The using statement assures that the service proxy will be properly disposed.
        using (_serviceProxy = ServerConnection.GetOrganizationProxy(serverConfig))
        {
            // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
            _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

            IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;


            using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
            {

                SoapLoggerOrganizationService slos = new SoapLoggerOrganizationService(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, service, output);

                //Add the code you want to test here:
                // You must use the SoapLoggerOrganizationService 'slos' proxy rather than the IOrganizationService proxy you would normally use.

                RetrieveEntityRequest request = new RetrieveEntityRequest
                {
                    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes, // use EntityFilter.All to get the entity as well as the attributes
                    LogicalName = Account.EntityLogicalName
                };
                RetrieveEntityResponse response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)slos.Execute(request);

            }


        }

    }
```

The resulting SOAP request (from the SOAPLogger's output.txt):

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <request i:type="a:RetrieveEntityRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Parameters xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>EntityFilters</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:EntityFilters" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata">Attributes</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>MetadataId</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:guid" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>RetrieveAsIfPublished</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:boolean" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">false</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>LogicalName</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">account</b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
        <a:RequestName>RetrieveEntity</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But as I commented my question, that is already the way I am doing this. I want to give a list of arguments to retrieve metadata from. I will give it another try myself with the SOAP Logger when I find some time to get things going.

Comment: This is good tip, especially for those staring out in CRM+SOAP. @dth You'll also need the JS to execute this against CRM. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594428.aspx You can also find some samples around the net. If you need some specific samples let me know and I can post a more generic sample here using the above SOAP.